# Scrapy API request 403 error issue. Works with requests, but not scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, scrapy, web-crawler

I've having a weird issue where my API request call works perfectly with standard request library, but it throws a 403 using scrapy only. The error message does not give me anything useful, except the "403 error" message. I have dropped my API key from this post, but you can easily obtain your own. Let me know if you need help getting an API key.

Working python code (no scrapy)

```
import requests

url = "https://www.airbnb.ca/api/v3/ExploreSections"

querystring = {"operationName":"ExploreSections","locale":"en-CA","currency":"CAD","_cb":"1db02z70xkcr690n1h3gp0py4nmy","variables":"{\"isInitialLoad\":true,\"hasLoggedIn\":false,\"cdnCacheSafe\":false,\"source\":\"EXPLORE\",\"exploreRequest\":{\"metadataOnly\":false,\"version\":\"1.8.3\",\"itemsPerGrid\":20,\"tabId\":\"home_tab\",\"refinementPaths\":[\"/homes\"],\"flexibleTripDates\":[\"february\",\"march\"],\"flexibleTripLengths\":[\"weekend_trip\"],\"datePickerType\":\"calendar\",\"placeId\":\"ChIJpTvG15DL1IkRd8S0KlBVNTI\",\"checkin\":\"2022-03-15\",\"checkout\":\"2022-03-16\",\"adults\":2,\"source\":\"structured_search_input_header\",\"searchType\":\"autocomplete_click\",\"query\":\"Toronto, ON\",\"cdnCacheSafe\":false,\"treatmentFlags\":[\"flex_destinations_june_2021_launch_web_treatment\",\"new_filter_bar_v2_fm_header\",\"merch_header_breakpoint_expansion_web\",\"flexible_dates_12_month_lead_time\",\"storefronts_nov23_2021_homepage_web_treatment\",\"flexible_dates_options_extend_one_three_seven_days\",\"super_date_flexibility\",\"micro_flex_improvements\",\"micro_flex_show_by_default\",\"search_input_placeholder_phrases\",\"pets_fee_treatment\"],\"screenSize\":\"large\",\"isInitialLoad\":true,\"hasLoggedIn\":false},\"removeDuplicatedParams\":false}","extensions":"{\"persistedQuery\":{\"version\":1,\"sha256Hash\":\"0d0a5c3b44e87ccaecf084cfc3027a175af11955cffa04bb986406e9b4bdfe6e\"}}"}

headers = {
    "x-airbnb-api-key": "YOUR_KEY",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.36",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

Scrapy spider code:

```
import scrapy
import json
from urllib.parse import urlencode


class ListingsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'listings'
    allowed_domains = ['airbnb.ca']


    def start_requests(self):
        params = {"operationName":"ExploreSections","locale":"en-CA","currency":"CAD","_cb":"1db02z70xkcr690n1h3gp0py4nmy","variables":"{\"isInitialLoad\":true,\"hasLoggedIn\":false,\"cdnCacheSafe\":false,\"source\":\"EXPLORE\",\"exploreRequest\":{\"metadataOnly\":false,\"version\":\"1.8.3\",\"itemsPerGrid\":20,\"tabId\":\"home_tab\",\"refinementPaths\":[\"/homes\"],\"flexibleTripDates\":[\"february\",\"march\"],\"flexibleTripLengths\":[\"weekend_trip\"],\"datePickerType\":\"calendar\",\"placeId\":\"ChIJpTvG15DL1IkRd8S0KlBVNTI\",\"checkin\":\"2022-03-15\",\"checkout\":\"2022-03-16\",\"adults\":2,\"source\":\"structured_search_input_header\",\"searchType\":\"autocomplete_click\",\"query\":\"Toronto, ON\",\"cdnCacheSafe\":false,\"treatmentFlags\":[\"flex_destinations_june_2021_launch_web_treatment\",\"new_filter_bar_v2_fm_header\",\"merch_header_breakpoint_expansion_web\",\"flexible_dates_12_month_lead_time\",\"storefronts_nov23_2021_homepage_web_treatment\",\"flexible_dates_options_extend_one_three_seven_days\",\"super_date_flexibility\",\"micro_flex_improvements\",\"micro_flex_show_by_default\",\"search_input_placeholder_phrases\",\"pets_fee_treatment\"],\"screenSize\":\"large\",\"isInitialLoad\":true,\"hasLoggedIn\":false},\"removeDuplicatedParams\":false}","extensions":"{\"persistedQuery\":{\"version\":1,\"sha256Hash\":\"0d0a5c3b44e87ccaecf084cfc3027a175af11955cffa04bb986406e9b4bdfe6e\"}}"}
        url = f"https://www.airbnb.ca/api/v3/ExploreSections?{urlencode(params)}"
        headers = {
            "x-airbnb-api-key": "YOUR_KEY",
            "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.36",
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
        }
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=url,
            method='GET',
            headers=headers,
            callback=self.parse_listings,
        )
    
    def parse_listings(self, response):
        resp_dict = json.loads(response.body)
        yield resp_dict
```

Comment: The best way to debug outgoing request differences is to capture the outgoing traffic using man in the middle traffic inspector. There are many open-source/free ones like https://mitmproxy.org/ and https://httptoolkit.tech/. Fire up the inspector, make one request from `requests` and one from `scrapy` and find the difference!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the headers, copy them from the browser and remove `cookie` and `content-length` if they are present.

```py
import scrapy
import json
from urllib.parse import urlencode


class ListingsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'listings'
    allowed_domains = ['airbnb.ca']

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.5
    }
    def start_requests(self):
        params = {"operationName":"ExploreSections","locale":"en-CA","currency":"CAD","_cb":"1db02z70xkcr690n1h3gp0py4nmy","variables":"{\"isInitialLoad\":true,\"hasLoggedIn\":false,\"cdnCacheSafe\":false,\"source\":\"EXPLORE\",\"exploreRequest\":{\"metadataOnly\":false,\"version\":\"1.8.3\",\"itemsPerGrid\":20,\"tabId\":\"home_tab\",\"refinementPaths\":[\"/homes\"],\"flexibleTripDates\":[\"february\",\"march\"],\"flexibleTripLengths\":[\"weekend_trip\"],\"datePickerType\":\"calendar\",\"placeId\":\"ChIJpTvG15DL1IkRd8S0KlBVNTI\",\"checkin\":\"2022-03-15\",\"checkout\":\"2022-03-16\",\"adults\":2,\"source\":\"structured_search_input_header\",\"searchType\":\"autocomplete_click\",\"query\":\"Toronto, ON\",\"cdnCacheSafe\":false,\"treatmentFlags\":[\"flex_destinations_june_2021_launch_web_treatment\",\"new_filter_bar_v2_fm_header\",\"merch_header_breakpoint_expansion_web\",\"flexible_dates_12_month_lead_time\",\"storefronts_nov23_2021_homepage_web_treatment\",\"flexible_dates_options_extend_one_three_seven_days\",\"super_date_flexibility\",\"micro_flex_improvements\",\"micro_flex_show_by_default\",\"search_input_placeholder_phrases\",\"pets_fee_treatment\"],\"screenSize\":\"large\",\"isInitialLoad\":true,\"hasLoggedIn\":false},\"removeDuplicatedParams\":false}","extensions":"{\"persistedQuery\":{\"version\":1,\"sha256Hash\":\"0d0a5c3b44e87ccaecf084cfc3027a175af11955cffa04bb986406e9b4bdfe6e\"}}"}
        url = f"https://www.airbnb.ca/api/v3/ExploreSections?{urlencode(params)}"

        headers = {
            "Accept": "*/*",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "Connection": "keep-alive",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "DNT": "1",
            "Host": "www.airbnb.ca",
            "Pragma": "no-cache",
            "Referer": "https://www.airbnb.ca/",
            "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
            "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
            "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
            "Sec-GPC": "1",
            "TE": "trailers",
            "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.36",
            "X-Airbnb-API-Key": "API_KEY",
            "X-Airbnb-GraphQL-Platform": "web",
            "X-Airbnb-GraphQL-Platform-Client": "minimalist-niobe",
            "X-Airbnb-Supports-Airlock-V2": "true",
            "X-CSRF-Token": "null",
            "X-CSRF-Without-Token": "1",
            "X-KL-Ajax-Request": "Ajax_Request",
            "X-Niobe-Short-Circuited": "true"
        }
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=url,
            method='GET',
            headers=headers,
            callback=self.parse_listings,
        )

    def parse_listings(self, response):
        resp_dict = response.json()
        yield resp_dict
```

Output:

```py
{'data': {'presentation': {'__typename': 'RootPresentationContainer', 'explore': {'__typename': 'ExplorePresentation', 'sections': {'__typename': 'ExploreSections', 'sections': [{'__typename': 'SectionContainer', 'id': 
...
...
...
```

Getting the request headers, example with chrome:

[image: Request headers]

Comment: That works. Some of those headers do not appear in my browser though. How did you find them? I tried using Chrome and Edge. I use the "Copy as cURL" command and then  use Insomnia to create the request. Why does the standard requests library not require those additional headers? In particular, these headers are not in my browser.['Accept-Encoding', 'Cache-Control', 'Connection', 'DNT', 'Host', 'Pragma', 'Sec-GPC', 'TE', 'X-Airbnb-GraphQL-Platscrapyform', 'X-KL-Ajax-Request'].

Comment: @JohnDoe open devtools in your browser, click on the network tab, and go to the webpage. You'll see the request headers there.

Comment: I have that page open now. I still don't see some of them. For example, 'X-KL-Ajax-Request' is not in "Request headers" or "Response headers". How could our browsers show different headers?

Comment: @JohnDoe see the edit

Comment: I still don't see some of those headers in my browser

Comment: That's weird. Did you make sure to open the network tab in devtools and only then open the webpage?

Comment: Ya, definitely doing that. I just worry that I won't be able to troubleshoot this issue in the future. I just don't have all the request that you have. For example, 'X-KL-Ajax-Request'. I find it strange that scrapy needs the extra headers, but standard requests library does not.